# How to execute python script in background from odoo

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, odoo

In my odoo app I want to execute a python script on a button click and I want it to run in background.I tried using subprocess library but it only runs in the foreground.

```
 result = subprocess.run(["python3", "/path-to-script/script.py"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, check=False)
```

Is there any way to execute a python script from odoo in the background.

Comment: Solved ? Feel free to up vote if my answer has helped you :--)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that in back-office is to create a "Server Action", which then will be added to the back-office "Action"-menu (in all views related to the chosen model):

Go to Configuration >
Turn url into debug modus by adding ?debug=1 to your url:
https://your-domain.dev.odoo.com/web?debug=1#action=8&model=ir.actions.server&view_type=list&cids=1&menu_id=4

In the last item of the Top menu, Click on Server-Action.

Click on the CREATE button:

- Choose the model, you want to add your Action-link to execute your script : Payment - in this example.
- As executed action, Choose : Python.
  Then, in the bottom panel: add your python script or call your model-def:

```py
    action = model.action_register_payment()
```

Example:

[image]

Under the top green button : CREATE / UPDATE, click on ADD AS CONTEXT ACTION,
so that in will be added to the Action Menu on the corresponding model in back-office (in all related views). The Action menu will appear in those views after you have checked records in the list-view for example:

[image]